# HC-05 not responding to AT Commands from Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: software, bluetooth

I'm trying to write AT commands to HC-05 module using Raspberry Pi Pico and MicroPython, nothing complicated. But for some reason my module doesn't respond. It works well in data mode and I'm able to send/receive messages from my phone via BT connection.

I've tried doing the same thing but using Arduino and my HC-05 was working. The module is blinking with interval of 2Hz so it's clearly in command mode.

Changing Baud Rate doesn't change anything.

Connecting TX to TX and RX to RX causes the first message to be `b'\x00'`, otherwise nothing is returned.

My Code:

```py
from machine import Pin,UART #importing PIN and PWM
import utime #importing time


#Defining UART channel and Baud Rate
uart = UART(0, 38400)

while True:
    command = input("COMM>")
    
    uart.write(command)
    utime.sleep(1)  # to make sure that HC-05 has time to respond
    print("checking", uart.any())
    
    if uart.any(): #Checking if data available
        data=uart.read() #Getting data
        data=str(data) #Converting bytes to str type
        print(data)
```

Ultimately I want to use `AT+INQ` to retrieve data about `RSSI` of nearby devices.

Comment: Typically when connecting two devices over UART, you connect the TX on one device to the RX on the other device, and vice-versa.

Comment: I've tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why I couldn't write AT commands in `MicroPython`, but when I've switched to `Rust` everything works as expected. [rp-hal](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal) is a great tool for embeded `Rust` on `RP2040` microcontrolers.

I suspect that it'd work on `C/C++` as well.

I also thank Ezward for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect TX <-> RX and RX <-> TX.  See https://www.instructables.com/Bluetooth-ModuleHC-05-With-Raspberry-Pi-Pico/

Here is another article that describes putting the HC-05 into AT mode, which involves driving the 'Key' pin high  https://www.instructables.com/Modify-The-HC-05-Bluetooth-Module-Defaults-Using-A/

Also note the default baud rate is 9600; your code is assuming 34800 baud.

Comment: It works for data mode but I intend to send AT commands. I've tried connecting TX <-> TX and RX <-> RX because this connection worked on Arduino (Commands were send via Serial Monitor and USB connection)

Comment: The default baud rate is 9600, so you can try that.  Also you need to drive the 'key' pin high to enter AT so you can change the baud rate; I don't see any code in your example that is doing that.  Again, I think you need to connect TX <-> RX and visa versa.  The second resource I linked shows it working that way on Arduino as well.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your reply, but unfortunately I've tried it all and it didn't work. I'm also driving the `key` pin high by just simply connecting it to the same 3.3V that powers the module. I'm currently trying to do the same thing on Pico but using C++ instead of MicroPython.

Comment: I also noticed the VCC for HC-05 is 3.6 to 5v, so perhaps it is flaky with 3.3v

Answer (score 0):

AT commands require `'\r\n'` for input. Try replacing `uart.write(command + '\r\n')`
In addition, for better viewing, converting bytes to str type:
`data=str(data, 'UTF-8')`